# Filtering out "InActive" customers from cbx list

Tags: c#, linq

Currently trying to filter out customers from a list whose status is set to "InActive" working with a method that generates the list of customers. The below code was my attempt to filter out the customers whose status is set to "InActive"  but the InActive customers are still in the list any help would be appreciated.

```
 public ABSCRCustomer GetCustomer(int custID)
    {
        
        ABSCRCustomer ret = new ABSCRCustomer();

        using (CSRAAEntities db = new CSRAAEntities())
        {

            ret = db.ABSCRCustomers.Where(x => x.CustomerID == custID && x.Status == "Active").FirstOrDefault();

        }//using
        

        return ret;
    }//GetCustomer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the `db.ABSCRCustomers` part, but the `FirstOrDefault()` may not be used like that.

You use `Where` (if you are awaiting a list as output), or you use `FirstOrDefault` if you wait an object as output.

```
List<ABSCRCustomer> listRet = db.ABSCRCustomers.Where(x.Status == "Active").ToList();
```

This will return the list of all `ABSCRCustomers` with Status="Active" (empty list if not found)

```
ABSCRCustomer ret = db.ABSCRCustomers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == custID && x.Status == "Active");
```

This will return the first customer with CustomerID=custID AND Status="Active". If no customer answer to this condition, you will return `null`

As I understood your question, you just need the `Where`, but then I don't see why you also filter on ID? Filter on ID means you want only one element as result.